# dateformat spelling format swift

Tags: swift

I am removing the current time from the current time and trying to find the minute difference. But it says 10/09/2019 13:13 and there is an error in the extraction process (I want to print as 1313) .1313 I can perform the extraction process. How do I print this data the way I want? I want to print dateFormat = "HHmm". In timertext2New.text, dateFormat = "dd / MM / yyyy HH: mm" like this. But I want to save it in HHmm format.

save12 output: 05/09/2019 10:48 but I want it to be "1048" . To perform extraction.

```
     let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
            timertext2New.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        let timehafıza2 = String(self.timertext2New.text!)

    let df2 = DateFormatter()
            df2.dateFormat = "HHmm"
            var str2 = df2.string(from: Date())
            str2 = timehafıza2
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(str2, forKey: "timertext2")

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let date = Date()
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HHmm"
        let hour = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

     var save12 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "timertext2")

        var fark : Int = (Int(hour)! - Int(save12))
}
```

Comment: Can you explain clearly the problem you have: what youneepect, what you get ?

Comment: What is `timehafıza2`? The `HHmm` string is overwritten by `timehafıza2` before being saved. And you clearly write a string and read an integer from `UserDefaults`.

Comment: When saving data in timertext2New.text, it does not save "HHmm"

Comment: I set the code @vadian

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? What result are you trying to get? Don’t tell me what your code is trying to do. What is the result of your function? What are you trying to save or show the user etc...

Comment: save12 output: 05/09/2019 10:48 but I want it to be "1048" . To perform extraction.

Comment: What output do you expect when the difference is >= 100 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty confusing and cannot work

- You convert a date from a date picker with format `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"`
- Then you create a string with format `"HHmm"` from the current date which will be destroyed immediately because
- You **overwrite** this string with the `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` string and save it to `UserDefaults`
- Later you read the value from `UserDefaults` as **integer** which returns 0 because the `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"` format is not representable by an integer.

My suggestion is to save all dates as `Date` and perform the date math with the dedicated methods of `Calendar`

Comment: When I save the whole date, I cannot subtract. So I can't make a mathematical collection.

Comment: The problem is solved if I can save the last 4 digits of the recorded date without the ":" sign.

Comment: You do can subtract dates because you can extract all date components separately and you can subtract dates in all granularities with `Calendar`. And please read the bullet list in my answer. It describes the mistakes you are making.